# ArrayList and Singleton object in Java

Tags: java, object, arraylist, singleton

I am facing a small problem with Java **ArrayList** and singleton Object.

I collected some data and put them to this **singleton Object** and put it into the **ArrayList**. I need to know, will it refer to the original Object or **get a copy of that Singleton Object**. I need to get separate copies to put in ArrayList.

Explain in detail...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ArrayList contains references to objects. Whatever references you put in the ArrayList, those references will be stored in there. For example, if you put 10 references (say r1, r2, ..., r10) which point to the same object, then you'll have an ArrayList of size 10 but all its members will point to the same object. This is how this works. So don't get confused, the ArrayList knows nothing about whether your objects are singletons or not, it deals just with storing references to objects.

Comment: so if I add 10 objects with that singleton object, all 10 elements will hold the same data. The data will be the data that has been added last.

Comment: No, you don't add objects, you add references to the list.

Comment: And the singleton pattern makes sure that only one object of this kind can exist in your application.

Comment: @chathura2020 - As peter says, you don't add *objects*, you add references to object(s). Even if you add 10 references of a Singleton object to an arraylist, you will have 10 different references in the arraylist pointing to one object.

Answer (score -1):

The list will store an original reference to your singleton.
I don'get it why you are going to get copies of singleton. This is not how a singleton works.

Comment: **copies of singleton** :P

Comment: I need to have only one object and when all the data has been collected need to collect them  separately. Actually I am developing an ebook reader(pagination part). The object will hold the text,images and once data is loaded for a page, they need to store, and fill the data again for empty object.